# What happens in case of writing/closing a java.net.Socket closed by peer?

Tags: java, windows, sockets, network-programming

Suppose I have an instance of `java.net.Socket`, which is an endpoint of a connection between two peers (`Windows` processes): my process and remote one. The remote process exited and closed its connection. Now I am trying to `write` and `close` my socket.

I would expect the `write` and `close` calls (or one of them) to fail and raise an exception (just like a `SIGPIPE` signal in Unix socket API) but they succeed.

What is the expected behaviour of `java.net.Socket` in this case ? Does it differ from the Unix socket API behaviour ? Does it work the same in Windows and Linux ?

Answer (score 1):

Well the situation is a little different to a pipe, because the OS doesn't necessarily know that the other end has closed the connection.  So ... in theory ... a number of writes to the socket could appear to work.  However, provided that the remote machine is still on the network, then the writer should eventually get an exception.  There's a good chance it will be thrown in a socket `flush` or `close`.

FWIW, the behaviour of a `java.net.Socket` is largely dictated by the way that the OS'es protocol stacks work.

Comment: Looks like `close` does not raise any exception either.

Comment: Yes. One of the peer processes is down though.